# Using Logic Apps, how can I input a formatted Table of results from an SQL Stored Procedure into SendGrid Email

Tags: email, sendgrid, resultset, azure-logic-apps

Once a day, I need to run an SQL Stored Procedure, which collects a list of results.  I then need to input the results, as a nice user friendly table, into an e-mail (SendGrid).

So far, I have setup all connections and got the Logic App to work but the e-mail it generates displays the results like this:

{"Table1":[{"CaseID":"1000001","DateOfUdate":"2020-06-09T11:34:57.483"},{"CaseID":"1000002","DateOfUdate":"2020-06-09T11:34:57.483"},{"CaseID":"1000003","DateOfUdate":"2020-06-09T11:34:57.483"},{"CaseID":"1000004","DateOfUdate":"2020-06-09T11:34:57.483"}]}

How can I get this to be displayed as a proper table?

```
Case ID    DateofUpdate
1000001    2020-06-09T11:34:57.483
1000002    2020-06-09T11:34:57.483
1000003    2020-06-09T11:34:57.483
1000004    2020-06-09T11:34:57.483
```

Below are images of my Logic App - please let me know if I need to provide more information.

[image: Schedule]

[image: Stored Procedure]

[image: SendGrid Email]

Comment: If the SendGrid Logic Apps connector supports HTML, you could use that to format the table. We do this via a Function App.

Comment: Yes it does support HTML, how would I write that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For this requirement, please refer to the steps I provided below:

**1.** I initialize a variable named "resultSetVar" and store the json data same to yours', use this variable to simulate your "ResultSets" data.
[image]

**2.** Then use "[Parse JSON](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-perform-data-operations#parse-json-action)" action to parse the json data.
[image]

**3.** After that, use "[Create HTML table](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-perform-data-operations#create-html-table-action)" action to create the html with the json array "Table1" from the "Parse JSON" action.
[image]

**4.** At last, put the "Output" from "Create HTML table" action into the "Email body" box.
[image]

**5.** Running the logic app, I received the email shown as below

[image]

Hope it helps~

Comment: That looks great.  How do I add the data from the Stored Procedure into the Values of Step 1? (initialize a variable named "resultSetVar").

Comment: Hi @seaside_escape You do not need to initialize a variable, just use the `ResultSets` as you put it in your "Send email(v4)" action. Put the `ResultSets` into the "Parse JSON" action "Content" box. If run it show error message that not allow you put `ResultSets` into "Parse JSON" directly, you can use a `string()` method to convert the `ResultSets` to string and then put it into "Parse JSON" action.

Comment: @seaside_escape If still have problem, please let me know.

Comment: When I get to "Create HTML Table" it doesn't give me the option to pick "Table1" from ParseJSON, I only see "Body"?

Comment: @seaside_escape Could you please share a screenshot of your "Parse JSON" action(include the schema which you input).

Comment: Sure. Where shall I put the screenshot - I can't add it into a comment?  Shall I create an Answer and put my screenshot in there?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215643/discussion-between-hury-shen-and-seaside-escape).

Comment: Thank you so much - it was the full schema I was missing and having the chat got it sorted.  Brilliant!

Comment: Just for info, schema should be:
{
    "properties": {
        "Table1": {
            "items": {
                "properties": {
                    "CaseID": {
                        "type": "string"
                    },
                    "DateOfUpdate": {
                        "type": "string"
                    }
                },
                "required": [
                    "CaseID",
                    "DateOfUpdate"
                ],
                "type": "object"
            },
            "type": "array"
        }
    },
    "type": "object"
}